# Distance of a point from a line

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $w\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a vector and denote $W=sp\{w\}$. Then
$W^{\perp}$ is also a one dimensional space i.e is a line, denote
this line as $l_{w}$.

Given a line we can shift it from the origin by a real number $b$:
$l_{w}+b$ is an affine space.

In a video lecture from Coursera I saw that given a point $A=(x_{A}^{(1)},x_{A}^{(2)})$
the distance from $A$ to $l_{w}$ was claimed to be 
$$
|\langle A-M,w\rangle|
$$

where $M$ is a point on $l_{w}$.

Can someone please explain this equality to me ?

The following is a screenshot from the lecture that should illustrate
the situation

[image]

Comment: If this isn't answered I'll help later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remember that if we have two vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ then the orthogonal projection of $\vec{u}$ over $\vec{v}$ is given by $$\frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}.$$

In your case, the distance from the point $A$ to the line is the distance from $H$ to $A.$ Of course, one can get explicitly $H$ and get the distance. However this is not necessary. Note that $|\vec{HA}|$ is the orthogonal projection of $\vec{AM}$ over $\vec{w}$ (and $M$ can be any point belonging to the line). This projection is given by

$$\frac{\langle \vec{AM},\vec{w}\rangle}{|\vec{w}|}.$$

If you assume that $\vec{w}$ is unitary then you get the expression

$$\langle \vec{AM},\vec{w}\rangle.$$

Comment: I don't understand, from "the dot product of two unitary vectors" I get that $A-M$ is a unit vector, why is that ? secondly, I don't understand why the said projection equals to the distance of $M$ from the line (did you mean $A$ ?, I would still not understand why, but $A$ makes more sense to me)

Comment: I have edited the answer for clarification.